# How to split an excel file into multiple worksheets with laravel-excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-excel

So I managed to create an excel file with data from a students table using Laravel-excel,
however, I want it to be split into small worksheets that represent separate groups of 20-25 students.

so far I've only found ways to split it into worksheets based on a condition like a group by sort of thing, but not based on a number of records for each worksheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider to do:

Create a StudentExport class:

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\Student;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;

class StudentExport implements WithMultipleSheets
{
    use Exportable;

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function sheets(): array
    {
        $sheets = [];
        $total = Student::count();
        $maxPage = (int) ceil($total/25);

        for ($page = 1; $page <= $maxPage; $page++) {
            $sheets[] = new StudentPerSheet($page);
        }

        return $sheets;
    }
}
```

Create a StudentPerSheet class

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\Student;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithTitle;

class StudentPerSheet implements FromQuery, WithTitle
{
    private $page;

    public function __construct(int $page)
    {
        $this->page = $page;
    }

    public function query()
    {
        return Student
            ::query()
            ->offset(($this->page - 1) * 25)
            ->limit(25);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function title(): string
    {
        return 'Page ' . $this->page;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
public function downloadStudents() 
{
    return (new StudentExport())->download('students.xlsx');
}
```

Comment: that worked thanks a lot, though I used skip/take insteade of offset and limit.

Comment: Yeah, I just made mistake at a place I pass parameters to offset and limit method